# How to overcome the forced authentication of oauth_aware?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I was going through some examples on how to implement oauth2 with a Google App Engine application and after deploying, I noticed that my @decorator.oauth_aware redirects the user to log-in page by default...

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936163/oauth2decorator-oauth-aware-forces-authentication/9937788) but there is no actual solution on how to go about with it :

```
class RootHandler(handlers.BaseHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_aware
  def get(self):
    variables = {'has_credentials' : decorator.has_credentials()}
    if decorator.has_credentials():
       #do something
       variables.update( {
          'url': decorator.authorize_url()
       })
    return self.render('index.html', variables)
```

What I want is, if the user is not logged-in/doesn't have credentials, display the index page with a sign in button (that has the authorisation url) and only afterwards redirect to root again and display further info.